# How to change the email and the password of the user in dart firebase

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to change the email and the password of the user in the Firestore and authentication so the user can log in with the updated email and password

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the email and the password of the user

I understand that you don't want these changes to be done by the user itself, but by another user, like an admin.

In this case you cannot use the Dart [`firebase_auth` library](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-library.html) because the [`updateEmail()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateEmail.html) and [`updatePassword()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updatePassword.html) methods **must be called by the user itself**.

---

On the other hand, with the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) you can modify an existing user's data (without authenticating as this user). To use the Admin SDK you need to do that from a privileged environment, like a server you manage or via Cloud Functions.

The following Node.js code can be used in a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions):

```
const uid =  .... // Specify the user's uid
getAuth()
  .updateUser(uid, {
    email: 'modifiedUser@example.com',
    password: 'newPassword',
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error updating user:', error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you I will use your solution on the admin side. however, I am trying to update the email and the password on the user's side but using updateEmail and updatePassword didn't work with me

Comment: Like I wrote in the anwser, `updateEmail()` and `updatePassword()` methods must be called by the user itself.

Comment: @Nouf: if you've tried the API and can't get it to work, edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).